# How to remove destroyed clones out of the Hierarchy in Unity2D

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, collision-detection

I made a 2D edge collider which on contact destroys the other gameobject. When I launch the game all the other gameobjects in fact get destroyed but the clones are still listed in the Hierarchy. How can I get rid of this? Thanks in advance.

The corresponding code is:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DestroyByBoundary : MonoBehaviour {

void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
{
    Destroy(other.gameObject);
}
```

}

[image: red box shows the problem] 
[image: inspector panel]

[image: inspector of destroyer object]

Comment: Are you sure that `other.gameObject` is actually the root `GameObject` and not a child of `Overlay(Clone)` or `Objects(Clone)`.

Comment: other.gameObject    is in a seperate class called Destroyer which is an empty gameObject with the edge collider and code

Comment: Can you show the Inspector panel for a `Destroyer` object?

Comment: There is nothing like "destroyed but still in hierarchy", if something is destroyed it gets removed from hierarchy on next frame. We need to know what is "Destroyer", what is "Objects" and "Overlay" and how you clone them.

Comment: Objects and Overlay are both prefabs. they are called with an invokeRepeating script. Destroyer is an edge collider which destroys every Object and Overlay.

Comment: Need to see the inspector for the objects being destroyed.  Likely @NoobsArePeople2 is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You must add a `Collider2D` to any `GameObject` that is to be destroyed by `DestroyedByBoundary`.  According to the [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html), just having the `RigidBody2D` isn't sufficient:

> Colliders are another kind of component that must be added alongside the Rigidbody in order to allow collisions to occur.

And for 2d, specifically:

> The collider types that can be used with Rigidbody 2D are the Circle Collider 2D, Box Collider 2D, Edge Collider 2D and Polygon Collider 2D

If you have the performance to spare, you should also change "Collision Detection" to "continuous".

Comment: I wouldn't suggest last line for this type of game.